# Thread Serialisation in Qt using QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I want to implement a condition as described in the [image: diagram shown below].

I want to make Thread 1 wait till Thread 2 has completed doing some job and after Thread 2 finishes the job Thread 1 should be made to wake up. Will I use a QWaitcondition or simple sleep() method of QThread? If QWaitcondition then how should I frame my wait condition...any suggestion is welcome..

Comment: while (true) do{
  Job1();
  Job2();
};

Comment: @MartinJames....can you be little more elaborate please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to do this would be to have your Thread1 Job1 function be called from a signal and have this function emit a signal to start Job2. When Job2 is finished, it would emit a signal that would then again start up Job1. Your diagram IS essentially what you'll want to do but just change the signal received TO BE the signal that hooks up to the jobs.

Unless you need the extreme timing requirements of having Job1 start up IMMEDIATELY as soon as job2 is done, you will not want to do any type of conditional 'waiting'. This will either suck down a core or be very inefficient.